# Image not appearing/not found in android popup

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog, bitmapfactory

```
String cardpath = Global.directory + longPressBtn.getText().toString() + ".jpg";
System.out.println(cardpath);

AlertDialog imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
imageDialog.setTitle("Title");
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardpopup, null); 
File imgFile = new File("cardpath");
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cardpath);

ImageView myImage = new ImageView(mContext);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

imageDialog.setView(view);
imageDialog.show();
```

I'm trying to make a popup with an image appear when a button is pressed. The code above is my attempt that isn't working. The `cardpath` variable is supposed to be a string of the absolute path of the image. However, nothing appears when the button is pressed. The image defined by the cardpath does indeed exist and I have external storage read permissions, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't see you scaling your image, check your logcat - you will probably see a line OpenGLRenderer  = Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture.